# How design ACM Word Template for SIG Site in latex

Tags: pdftex, acm

I'm search for ACM Word Template for SIG Site  in latex but I couldn't find it . Do you have any idea how to design it in latex?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template ?

Comment: The style used by ACM conferences is also available on CTAN, the package is `acmart`, and the "old"style was called `acmconf`

Comment: @LianTzeLim I have checked  acm website , but I couldn't find the same format

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct template? It looks like the old ACM conference template, which is somehow outdated. Does you publishing venue really rely on this old style, or do they want the new `acmart`—which is what most conferences I've seen lately do.

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk I submitted my paper with sig-alternate but they told me I should follow the the above approach . I don't know what is differences.